# Why can't I restrict all from executing a folder?

Tags: command-line

Why isn't the code working?

```
mkdir new_folder
cd new_folder
cd ..
chmod 666 new_folder
cd new_folder //this is allowed
ls -la
total 0
drwxrw-rw-   2 David  staff   68 Mar 16 18:20 .
drwx------@ 10 David  staff  340 Mar 16 18:20 ..
Davids-MacBook-Pro-2:new_folder David$ cd ..
ls -al | grep new_folder
drwxrw-rw-   2 David  staff      68 Mar 16 18:20 new_folder
Desktop David$
```

Comment: Hi David, it's somewhat unclear what you're asking. Can you reformat your question to make clear what you're trying to do and what the issue is? Also, you can make text formatted as code using triple quotes or indenting with tabs.

Answer (score 2):

A folder/directory requires at least one executable bit or you won't be able to open/traverse it. Therefore `chmod 666 folder` is a pointless command.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my formatting error! Sorry about that. So there are no instances where a file could not be executable by u,g, or o?

If I

Comment: @David The file's executable bit has another meaning than the exec bit of a directory. The latter set means that you can browse a directory, the first means the file is executable. If no exec bit is set (the octal view of the permissions has **no** odd number (e.g. 644 or 444)) nobody can open/browse the folder.

Comment: So if I 

    chmod 666 somefile.txt 
    cd somefile.txt

 I should get blocked. Right? So that's my understanding of what should happen and I'm trying to figure out why it is not happening. Or if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: @David you can't open and read a file ~/testdir/test.txt if testdir has 666 permissions (and test.txt at least 400) because you are not allowed to traverse the folder testdir!

Comment: Let me first apologize for not being clear in my first attempt in posing my question. So currently, I can create a directory, chmod 666 said directory, and then cd into said directory. I was taught that I would not be able to cd or execute into said directory. I'm wondering why I can (if I'm not root) or if what I was taught was wrong and why?